# Android findViewById on dynamically created textviews in custom list adapter does not seem to work

Tags: android, list, textview

I'm building a configuration program which prints out value/item lists dynamically. Sometimes you will have one item to output, for example, a name, but other times you might have multiple items that you want outputted, for example, an ip address, username, password, etc.

The idea is to build up a list dynamically depending on the amount of parameters outputted. On a small screen the amount of parameters might be 2, but in landscape mode or on a tablet the amount of parameters might be much higher.

I have this working when I have a hard coded XML file with Android IDs, i.e. referring to

```
android:id="@+id/item1
```

but I'm struggling with doing this programmatically. Before the edit I was doing this with IDs but on advice I am now rather trying this with tags.

Here are all the relevant parts of the code. Is a multi-line list of parameters is outputted we branch to buildLayout to build up the custom layout:

```
public void processAsyncTask(String result) {       
        ConfigList list = getConfigList(result);
        ArrayList<ConfigCollection> mParamsList = list.getAllItems();
        // Once we have a list of parameters we build the layout according to size
        buildLayout(mParamsList.size());
        mMultiRowAdapter = new ParamsAdapter(this, R.layout.multi_row_config, mParamsList);         
        mCollectionListView.setAdapter(mMultiRowAdapter);           
        }
```

Here is buildLayout:

```
private void buildLayout(int size) {                
    TableRow tr = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row_multi_row);                       
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setId(i);
        tv.setTag("id" + String.valueOf(i));
        tv.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
        tv.setText("id" + String.valueOf(i));
        tr.addView(tv);
    }               
}
```

And here is how I am trying to refer to the IDs:

```
/**
     * Custom Array Adapter with a view that displays multi-line item/value pairs 
     */
    private class ParamsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ConfigCollection> {

        private ArrayList<ConfigCollection> objectList;

        public ParamsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<ConfigCollection> objectList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objectList);
            this.objectList = objectList;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.multi_row_config, null);             

            // It works with hard coded IDs, e.g.:
            TextView tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item1);
            TextView tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item2);

            // BELOW DOES NOT, tv1 and tv2 is null after assignment
            TextView tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewWithTag("id0");
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewWithTag("id1");
```

Here is the XML file that I am using to test with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout    
    android:id="@+id/table_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

     <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    />

    <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row_multi_row"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"              
        android:text="item1"    
        android:padding="3dip"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"              
        android:text="item2"
        android:padding="3dip"  
    />  

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

EDIT:
I've isolated the problem further visible here with screenshots. It seems in buildLayout I am adding textviews but in the custom array adapter the layoutinflator does not find these fields. I've also updated the code to try and work with tags instead of IDs.

Debug from buildLayout. Notice four children, the two fixed in the XML code and two created

[image: Debug from buildLayout. Notice four children, the two fixed in the XML code and two created]

Debug from ParamsAdapter. Notice only two children at this stage where I am actually trying to access these objects.

[image: Debug from ParamsAdapter. Notice only two children at this stage]

Comment: You may try tv.setId("sometext"+i);  appending sometext to ID. I suspect, setting i might contradicting with someID.

Comment: @thinjksteep so you telling us that setId can be used with String?

Comment: @Selvin You are correct setId complains if you try to use it with a string parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating items programmatically, I would advise using the "tag" parameter. It's not as fast as id, but then you are not worried about speed for this - as long as you have the parent view you can "findViewWithTag" - see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html - scroll down to findViewWithTag

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this, adding `tv.setTag(i)` and then later on referring to it by doing `TextView tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewWithTag(0)` but tv1 still ends up being null. I wonder if it's not the order in which I am doing things, it's almost like I am referring to something that is not there...

Comment: Try setting the tag with a string and retrieving via a string?

Comment: I tried that by using `"id" + String.valueOf(i)` but no luck. I'm starting to doubt the XML file. I'm thinking the layoutinflator works with textviews within the listview but I'm creating new textviews outside of the listview. Possibly I need to refer to a child but how? Also I am wondering if the inflator service works with hard coded XML **and** dynamically added textviews.